# Error durante una operación criptografica

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cuando ejecuto la app, compila bien sin problemas pero antes de mostrarme el index que tengo, me arroja un pantallazo de un error:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Error durante una operación
> criptográfica. Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la
> solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener
> más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción:
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error durante una
> operación criptográfica.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 26:             Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c
> => c.webUserUniqueId == userId); Línea 27:             // place the entry in memory Línea 28:             this.Deserialize((Cache == null)
> ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache")); Línea 29:
> } Línea 30:

Y el codigo en el cual me marca error.

```
public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            userId = signedInUserId;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
            // look up the entry in the database
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            // place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits,"ADALCache"));
        }
```

Es en la parte del this.Deserialize

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Una disculpa, ya lo edite. Gracias

Comment: No te están diciendo que por favor nos pongas a ir a imgur con otro clic. Te están diciendo que, en lo posible, las trazas de error vayan como texto. Si te toca poner una captura de algo por algún motivo, la puedes poner directo en SO y no ponerla por allá afuera. Por eso te edité y te revertí el cambio. Edita tu pregunta si puedes poner una traza más completa del error, como texto. De lo contrario, no le añadas clics a la lectura

Comment: yo podria apostar que se cual es tu problema.. pero sin ver el error (que no veo, me lo bloquea un proxy) es dificil ayudarte...

Comment: Y ahora, que hace Deserialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de "jugar con él" durante más de unas horas, entré en la base de datos que tengo y eliminé todas las filas de la tabla UserTokenCaches. Ejecuté la aplicación, superé el mensaje de error criptográfico. Se creó un nuevo registro de token de caché y se insertó en la tabla.